# How to load external data with PhoneGap App

Tags: cordova

I'm new to PhoneGap development.  Since html and related files reside on in the app on the mobile device itself, there is no compiling done.

How then do I access external dynamic data?  At first glance, I assume it's through web services, AJAX, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You right, ajax must be used.

You have a tutorial (with jquery mobile) here:

http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2574

It´s posible that you must include extra security policies to make the ajax request, plus in the server side include this header header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); replace the asterix with your domain.

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

you can do that using jquery ajax request, but remember to make the `crossDomain` option to `true` and to put your domain inside the `white list domains` inside the `plist` files

Answer (score 2):

to load external page if you are already online just use ABSOLUTE PATHS in you ajax call:

```
http://www.yourdomain.xxx/scripts/script.php
```

if testing locally, just do the same, with

```
  http://localhost/your_testing_folder/script.php
```

in both cases find the file CONFIG.XML in the

```
/project_name/project_name/config.xml
```

and add the whitelist URL:

```
<!-- <content src="http://mysite.com/myapp.html" /> for external pages -->

<content src=www.yourdomain.xxx/" /> for external pages
<content src="http://localhost:8888/" /> <-- this is localhost for local testing purp.
<content src="index.html" />
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you should use JSON to get dynamic data from server

and then you can fetch it with Jquery and you will be able to perform normal get and post too.